# Unknown architecture when attempting to install GHCup on Red Hat linux

Tags: haskell, installation, redhat, cabal, ghcup

I would like to install Cabal on my POWER8 RHEL 7.9 system.

Instructions [here](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/getting-started.html) and then [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/#) suggested to run this command.

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
```

Upon running this I answered all the questions with the default answer and then it said:-

```
Unknown architecture: ppc64le
```

So, how do I install haskell, and thus cabal on my system?

Comment: Is this really a machine with Power ISA processor, or is it actually an x86-64 or ARM64 that's just misclassified for some reason?

Comment: If you're not sure, you may be able to learn more by poking around in `/proc/cpuinfo` and searching the web for info on what you see in there.

Comment: It's really a power machine

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's going to be difficult. Though it seems there are people who have managed to port GHC to PowerPC, this is at any rate not officially maintained. I suspect the most realistic option for running Haskell code on such a machine is to compile to WebAssembly, though that will for sure limit what you can do with it.

Comment: All I actually want is shelltestrunner, so perhaps there is another way to get that instead of GHCup -> Haskell -> Cabal -> shelltestrunner

Comment: Well, I got cabal installed on my ppc64le system, but it doesn't understand the package index file that it has just downloaded! Anyway, that's another different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerPC is a Tier 2 platform for GHC (See https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/platforms). That means that it probably works, but it is not supported by the core development team.

https://www.haskell.org/ghc/distribution_packages has details of where you can get various of the tier 2 platforms from, and specifically for ppc64le which you are after, there is a section titled, "Fedora and EPEL" which suggests you can install it thus:-

```
dnf install ghc.
```

Of course, first you'll have to install `dnf` which is in the EPEL.

Failing that you'll probably have to compile GHC from source. You can try following the instructions here: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/building/hadrian, but that is going to take some effort.

Comment: Your answer led me to the answer, so I have updated it and accepted it. Cheers!

Comment: Ah, I was confused by their inconsistent use of `PowerPC`, `powerpc`, and `ppc`. Great to hear you've found your answer.